# Making Gears using helix-3d-toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I'm using the Helix toolkit with WPF (in C#), and I'm trying to make a program that generates a user-specified gear train. Currently, gears are represented as cylinders in the UI but I would like it to look more like gears with teeth and other properties (bore diameter, face width). What would the best way be to solve such an issue? And are there any tutorials/resources available?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own mesh builder to generate gears. Or use other tools to create gear mesh, export as obj and then load into helix toolkit.

Answer (score -3):

you must use 3d modeller program. then you must import your program

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).